# Configuring log shipping from on premises to Azure IaaS SQL

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, log-shipping

I am trying to configure log shipping from on premises server to azure Iaas SQL VM. Please let me know the method and limitations.

Mainly i wanted to know how we will configure network shared path between on prem , azure and how backup and restore will happen

Answer (score 0):

So for the second question.

No different as you would backup and restore things between 2 VM's in your Datacenter. Don't see a point to expand on this one.

As for the first question. You would want to create a Site-to-Site VPN between Azure and your own Datacenter, after that you would treat you Azure VM as a VM in your Datacenter.

As for the setup guide: there are a lot of guides running around in the internet, I'll provide a link to the [Azure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-site-to-site-create)
, where you can look up both ARM and ASM ways to do that.